# How do you get the force acting from the first robot link on the second robot link knowing the forces and moments in the base of the robot?

Tags: robotic-arm, dynamics, torque, inverse-dynamics

Inverse dynamics (ID) is the concern of finding the required joint forces from a specification of the joint positions, velocities, and accelerations. In the figure bloew, the ID problem would be the concern of finding the forces $f_{1}$, $f_{2}$ and $f_{3}$, from a specification of $q_{i}, \dot{q_{i}}, \ddot{q_{i}}$, where i = 1, 2, 3, and an external force $f_{1}^{ext}$.

[image]

It is well known that Recursive Newton Euler Algorithm (RNEA) can be used to solve the inverse dynamic problem. I consider the version of RNEA from the book "Rigid Body Dynamics Algorithms" by Roy Featherstone. This version of RNEA takes as input a vector of joint angles and gives as output a vector of torques in the joints. During the execution of the RNEA the spatial forces are calculated, which act from one body element over the connecting joint on the next body element. Thus, in addition to the torques in the joints, one also gets the spatial forces acting through the joints.

Here is the pseudo code of the RNEA. In this version, the acceleration $a_{0}$ of the first robot element was set equal to the gravitational acceleration. If this trick is used, the calculated values of $a_{i}$ and $f_{i}^B$ (B stands for "body") will no longer be the actual acceleration and net force for body $i$, but will be balanced by the gravitational acceleration and force vectors, respectively. (The gravitational force on body $i$ is $I_{i} a_{g}$.)

[image]

(Consider X, I and S matrices as given, RNEA does have access to these matrices)

Imagine you are now able to get the forces and moments acting in the base of the robot. For example, someone has installed the robot on a force plate and noted the resulting forces and moments. I marked the measured force with the red arrow in the first picture. We can concatenate the measured forces and moments to the spatial force $f_{0}$ = (Fx, Fy, Fz, Mx, My, Mz).

**Now to the question**: Can we calculate the force $f_{1}$ (see the figure from above) from this spatial force $f_{0}$? If so, then how? What must be done with $f_{0}$ to get to $f_{1}$?
In my opinion it should be possible. My approaches were:

1. Considering the force $f_{0}$ as an external force.
2. Considering the force $f_{0}$ as the force with which the robot base acts on the force plate. The force plate in this case has to be considered as another robot part, for example as another link connected to the base by a fixed-joint.

Note: It would be definitely wrong to use this measured space force $f_{0}$ as $f_{1}$ without any transformation between $f_{0}$ and $f_{1}$ or something else.

After a few days of work I come to the conclusion that I didn't consider something in my calculations. At least I hope so. Alternatively, the result would be that you can't get from $f_{0}$ to $f_{1}$ in any way. If you have an idea but need more information, ask me or read "5.3 The Recursive Newton-Euler Algorithm" in the book "Rigid Body Dynamics Algorithms" by Roy Featherstone. Or both. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found the error in my calculations. Everything seems to be working right now, the joint torques are calculated correctly (at least they look believable). I'll do a few more tests with the robot and then post an answer.